# opt101 (photodiode) adjust voltage output

Tags: arduino, photodiode

I'm using the popular [OPT101](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=opt101) photodiode with 5V. How can I scale the output between 0 and 5V (or as close to that range as possible)? Now the output is ca 0-400mV (maximum is room light here).

I'm a noob, and if I had more experience, I would be able to figure out with >[the datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opt101.pdf)< what Pin would lead to the desired 'amplification', but I have no clue where to start. I did follow the instructions outlined in the datasheet (pinned below), i.e. all recommended Pins are connected (Vs has 5V in that diagram, V- is connected to ground).

As far as I know, the circuit contains an opamp, that is probably usable to scale the output to the desired range, but I find no instructions about how to adjust it - I have a strong suspicion exactly one resistor or pin connection is needed to achieve this...

I should add, I was hoping I can achieve this without applying any negative voltage, since that seems a bit more complicated, and I avoided it wherever possible here

[image]

Circuit schematic from datasheet:

[image]

Comment: To increase the output voltage you would need to increase the value of the 1 Mohm resistor, which is inside the IC so **you cannot change it**. There is no "amplification" pin. You will need a circuit to provide extra amplification, for example a "non inverting amplifier" that uses an **opamp**. Also you cannot get exactly 5 V output when your supply is also 5 V, so settle for slightly less than 5 V or use a higher supply voltage. Also, why do you need 5 V (instead of 400mV)? If you connect the voltage to an ADC maybe you can more easily change the ADC's range.

Comment: That's the issue, I want to maximize the range of the ADC (that goes from 0 to 5 volts), anything that maximizes the output towards that range would, I guess, be beneficial in terms of having a better signal resolution

Comment: **Maybe** you could disconnect pin 4 and not use the internal 1 Mohm resistor. Then connect a 5V / 0.4 V * 1 Mohm = 12.5 Mohm resistor between pins **2** and **5**. Also put a 3 pF capacitor in parallel with that 12.5 Mohm resistor. Note that **this might not work as expected** due to the high value 12.5 Mohm resistor. But it is worth a try. What ADC are you using? For example the ADC in an Arduino can very easily be re-configured to a different voltage range.

Comment: With a supply of 5 V the output of this IC can go only up to around 3.7 V, see table 6.5 "Voltage output, high" in the datasheet. So instead of 12.5 M ohm use a lower value.

Comment: The ADC I'm using is basically an arduino. But essentially I just want to maximize the signal range from 0-5V from the sensor

Comment: Clear but as I explained, you cannot get 5 V range because the OPT101 can only drive its output to supply - 1.3 V = 3.7 V. So aim for that instead. Then use the Vref pin on the Arduino and put 3.7 V on it using a voltage divider. Then program the Arduino such that it will use the Vref pin as the ADC's reference. The "must have 5 V" isn't feasible so don't aim for it.

Comment: I understand, will rephrase to 'as close to 5V range as possible'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add external resistance, for example between 4 and 5 pins, with some shunt capacitance. There is a table in the datasheet.

[image]

About 10M in parallel with 5pF, which will give you a gain of 11x what you have now, so about 4.4V rather than 0.4V.

It's not advisable to use a breadboard because of stray capacitance, but if you try it, you might want to increase the shunt capacitance to about 10pF or a bit more to ensure stability. The response will be more sluggish as a result.

Comment: thanks a lot! is there an easy explanation as to why the 5pF is needed? I don't want to compromise the speed of the sensor and that is usually what happens with capacitors (sorry for the noob perspective), is why I'm asking. I should note, I soldered these connections freehand, without breadboard, and with very long connection cables (1-2m)

Comment: The PD has a whole bunch of capacitance due to the large sensing junction size and if you don't add the shunt capacitance to the feedback resistance you create a delay in the feedback which can lead to oscillation. TI don't show this option but you could also try dividing the feedback down with a 10K+1K resistor and no external capacitance.

Comment: I think I understand. The capacitor will 'flatten out' oscillation by storing some energy and releasing it when the oscillations occur, which can be (somehow) present on the feedback line

Comment: You have the choice of using the internal network or not. Both options are shown in the datasheet. I suggest adding the external parts between pins 4 and 5 rather than leaving 4 open and adding an external network between 5 and 2 because it's a bit less sensitive to stray capacitance.